# when GDB debugging... why it not continue when I give them 'c' or 'si' or 'ni' after break?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

okay... this is more like a tutor question..

I give them 'c' for continue but it stucks in same breakpoint

"breakpoint already hit 232 times"

Comment: Is the breakpoint set inside a loop, such that when you continue, it hits the breakpoint again the next time through?

Comment: oh I think you are right... so is there way to out that loop?

Comment: *out of the loop... sorry my english

Comment: Disable the breakpoint and continue